# Ink effect extended to a container

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, md-card

Let's take thee follwing code for example:

```
<md-card>
    <md-button>Ink effect<md-button>
</md-card>
```

I would like it to when I click on the button to have an ink effect starting from the button and overlaying the whole card, like [this](https://dribbble.com/shots/3163892-Ink-Ripples-Material-Motion):

[image: Card + Ripple]

Is it possible in AngularJS Material?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer:**

Based on better understanding updating my Codepen. Please check it out.

**Codepen:** [here](https://codepen.io/kai1992cool/pen/oeEVVg)

**Initial Answer:**

Do you want something like this. You can build on top of this example if its right.

**JSFiddle:** [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Kai_Draord/v41y3ze2/1/)

CSS:

```
.card:hover{
    background-color:white !important;
 }
.card{
  box-sizing: border-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    height:300px;
    width:500px;
    background-color:white;
 }
```

Comment: I would like something similar but with an md-card and on click the overlay covers the entire md-card. I would like to be white (but I guess for this part, only css is needed). Only the button must be clickable not the container.